# Editing Joomla Category blog view

Tags: joomla

What file would I need to edit to change (overide) the Joomla 3.3 on Centos default category blog view ?

Im using the Yoo theme Katana theme ...

Ta,

Comment: do you want to change the blog items or the way the blog view is structured?

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is 1st override the category blog view view in your template. Because editing core files are not preferred.

Here’s a simple tutorial to override the layout of the ‘category blog’ view.

First of all we need to create the override folder `/templates/current_template/html/com_content/category/`

Paste and copy the `blog_item.php` file located in `/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl` into the override folder we previously created.

edit the `blog_item.php` file as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Default category blog listing path is:

```
{JoomlaSite}/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php
```

That includes other related templates respectively:

```
{JoomlaSite}/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php

{JoomlaSite}/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_links.php

{JoomlaSite}/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_children.php
```

**In Joomla 3.3.x versions category blog layout is already overridden by default beez3 template**, so you need to refer a copy from beez3 templates for latest changes(if any). Path for that is;

```
{JoomlaSite}/templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog.php

{JoomlaSite}/templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

{JoomlaSite}/templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog_links.php

{JoomlaSite}/templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog_children.php
```

You can use this files to override respectively, based on which type of change is required to your current need. **You can copy & paste respective files to your current theme's folder like this;**

```
{JoomlaSite}/templates/{Your_Current_Theme}/html/com_content/category/blog.php
```

**Replace {Your_Current_Theme} with your template folder name.**